# Simplify Boolean Expression ABC' + A'BC + A'B'C'

Tags: boolean-algebra

Can anyone help me simplify this boolean expression?

ABC' + A'BC + A'B'C'

EDIT: (only using AND gates (multiply [(x)(x)]) and OR gates (addition [+]))

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simpliest form of the expression.

You can verify this through Karnaugh map(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map)

A Karnaugh map of this question is shown below and it's clear to see there's cancellation.

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 C\backslash \text{AB} & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\
\hline
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$